# Combination with repeated floor operations same as the whole combination?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, products

This question involves both math and programming, but the main inquiry in nature is mathematical.

There is a LeetCode question called [Unique Paths](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/) that asks the number of ways that one can reach the lower-right corner of a $m \times n$ grid if you start in the upper-left corner and want to reach the lower-right corner, only being able to move down or right at any step.

Visualization of the $3 \times 7$ case, for example:

[image: LeetCode unique paths 3x7 example]

[One mathematical approach that was suggested](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/discuss/2362027/3-Approaches%3A-DP-Recursion-Math) is to compute $\begin{pmatrix}m + n - 2 \\ m - 1\end{pmatrix}$ as the question is equivalent to asking the number of ways to select $m - 1$ downwards moves from a total of $m + n - 2$ moves to reach the lower-right corner.

However, the programming solution that was proposed essentially computes the following:

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{1 \cdot n}{1} \right\rfloor (n + 1)}{2} \right\rfloor (n + 2)}{3} \right\rfloor \cdots (n + m - 2)}{\vdots \atop m - 1} \right\rfloor
$$

So, my question is how does the solution guarantee that the above is equivalent to $\left\lfloor \frac{(m + n - 2)!}{(m - 1)!(n - 1)!} \right\rfloor$ without any loss of data from the repeated application of the floor operator?

**Edit:**

The [accepted answer from Sil](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567416/378085) helped me out the most intuitively. Though, the [inductive proof of how each step results in a combination by Mike](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567437/378085) also helped very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The division is applied in cases where denominator already divides numerator, so there is no remainder. This is because $\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}$ is an integer for all $k=1,2,\dots$ (see for example [Division of Factorials [binomal coefficients are integers]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192/290240) or [Proof that a Combination is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601) for some proofs of this fact). Hence the result of the division is an integer and there is nothing to round (floor function).

Using your notation, first it's clear that $1$ divides $n$ and so $\frac{1 \cdot n}{1}=n$ and $\lfloor n \rfloor=n$. Then $n(n+1)$ is a multiple of $2$ (one of two consecutive integers will be even), so $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is an integer and so $\lfloor \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \rfloor= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And so on... In $k$-th step you take the above binomial coefficient about which we already know is an integer, and so $1\cdot 2\cdots k$ divides $n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)$, hence $k$ divides $\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots (k-1)}$ which we have from the previous step.

From more programming point of view, the step you refer to I believe is `ans = ans * x / y;`, which in C is evaluated as `ans = (ans * x) / y;`. The division operator here is an integer division so in principle it could also perform some rounding, but as explained above, `ans * x` is already a multiple of `y` so this is not an issue here.

Comment: I now get the intuition. Thank you for that! However, the "And so on..." part confuses me. I see how you get the mod 1 and mod 2 cases, but I find it hard to extrapolate from that point.

Comment: You continue by picking the next binomial coefficient, for $k=3$ we have $\binom{n+2}{3}$ is an integer (I assume you know this fact, it can be proven on its own if you don't), but $\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}$, so we know $2\cdot 3$ divides $n(n+1)(n+2)$, and so $3$ divides $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$. By same process you know $k$ divides $\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots (k-1)}$, which you have from previous step.

Answer (score 3):

Let us give names to the intermediate values of this calculation. Let $x_0=1$, and for each $i\in \{1,2,\dots,m-1\}$, let
$$
x_{i+1}=\left\lfloor\frac{x_i\cdot (n+i)}{i+1}\right\rfloor
$$
We will prove by induction on $i$ that $$x_i=\binom{n+i-1}{i},\qquad i\in \{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$$ In particular, the last value is $x_{m-1}=\binom{m+n-2}{m-1}$, so this would prove the algorithm is computing the correct value.

For the base case, we must prove $x_0=\binom{n-1}{0}$. Since $\binom{n-1}{0}=1$, this matches the definition of $x_0$.

For the inductive step, given $i\ge 0$, we assume $x_i=\binom{n+i-1}{i}$, and must prove $x_{i+1}=\binom{n+i}{i+1}$.
\begin{align}
x_{i+1} 
  &= \left\lfloor\frac{x_i\cdot (n+i)}{i+1}\right\rfloor
\\&= \left\lfloor\binom{n+i-1}{i}\cdot \frac{n+i}{i+1}\right\rfloor
\tag{Inductive hypothesis}
\\&= \left\lfloor\binom{n+i}{i+1}\right\rfloor
\tag{Absorption identity}
\\&= \binom{n+i}{i+1}
\tag{Floor of integer is self}
\end{align}
The absorption identity I am using is
$$
\binom{t}{k}=\binom{t-1}{k-1}\frac{t}{k},\qquad k\ge 1
$$
which is easy to prove by converting everything to factorials, i.e. using $\binom tk=t!/[k!\cdot (t-k)!]$.

Comment: That clears it up quite a bit! Every step is a combination itself as you have mentioned, which makes it an integer. Thank you! Then, the only quandary that this leaves me with is the intuition for why the product from i = 0 to k of (x+i)/(i + 1) ≡ 0 (mod k + 1). I'll probably ask that as a separate question later.

Comment: @GigiBayte2 To your comment, see the answers to [the product of $n$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial). The second answer gives a proof by induction, while the third answer gives a proof by counting prime factors. (Also, here is my version of the prime-counting proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2869484/177399).